# How to encode UTF8 characters into Base64 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, base64

I tried like this when handling chinese, but the output is <strike>messy code</strike> garbled:

```
var a = "你好";
undefined
a
"你好"
a = unescape(encodeURIComponent(a));
"ä½ å¥½"
a
"ä½ å¥½"
```

compared to handling English:

```
var a = "Hello";
undefined
a
"Hello"
a = unescape(encodeURIComponent(a));
"Hello"
```

Here is my whole code:

```
var content = $("div#test").html();
content = unescape(encodeURIComponent( content ));
content = window.btoa(content);
content = "data:image/svg+xml;filename:{{ request.session.access_token.uid }}.svg;base64," + content;
```

**UPDATED:**

What I am trying to do is encoding a generated SVG as data url for user to download. I solved this problem by converting SVG to canvas (using CanVG) first and use html2canvas to generate base64 ... finally it works ...

Comment: What is your input and what do you need as output?

Comment: how is your output related to the code?

Comment: What do you mean by "the output is messy code"?

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa

Comment: @thg435 Yours doesn't work with Chinese characters. By encoding and decoding "你好", you get "ä½ å¥½", which is the problem the OP has.

Comment: @Antony: it's not "mine" for starters. From what I can see, both functions on that page work just fine for OP's input.

Comment: @thg435 Ok. It isn't "yours", but I just ran it in the console and it doesn't work for "你好".

Comment: @torazaburo It means unrecognizable characters due to wrong encoding.

Comment: Try roundtripping this, and you'll see it works fine: `decodeURIComponent(escape(unescape(encodeURIComponent("東京"))))
"東京"`, even thought the intermediate result looks like funny characters--because it IS funny characters.

Comment: @torazaburo I run: window.btoa(decodeURIComponent(escape(unescape(encodeURIComponent("東京"))))) on Chrome 24, got error: Error: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5

Answer (score 4):

Try roundtripping this, and it works fine:

```
decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent("‌​東京"))))))
```

Whether or not some intermediate result appears to be garbled is not relevant.

The problem with the `window.btoa(decodeURIComponent(escape(unescape(encodeURIComponent("東京")))))` in one of the comments is the calls are not balanced and not in the right order.

Comment: You answer do run withou error in Chrome. But what I want is base64 provided by window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent("‌​東京")), which is not recognize correctly in Chrome when opening base64 data URL.

Comment: thanks this seems to be the simplest solution ive found so far. im going to try it out some more.
http://jsfiddle.net/gfjsycqd/